# Want to remove the double quotes from the strings

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, replace, c#-3.0

I saw some questions here related to removing double quotes. But it not solved my Issue. They told to use Replace or Trim functions. I used but the problem remains.

My code:

```
DataTable dt = TypeConveriontHelper.ConvretExcelToDataTable(SourceAppFilePath);
        string targetPath = BatchFolderPath + @"\" + "TRANSACT.INX";
        StreamWriter wrtr = null;
        wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetPath);
        for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            string rowString = "";
            for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
                if (y == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\"";
                }
                else
                {
                    rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\"~";
                }
            }           
            rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
            wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
        }
        wrtr.Close();
        wrtr.Dispose();
```

I tried by using `rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();` in above code. But double quotes are present as it is. Proveide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect if you read the answers in the other questions *carefully*, you'll get the answer... Note that you should also be using `using` statements in order to dispose of resources even if there's an exception.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to assign it back to `rowString`:

```
rowString = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

**[Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).**

`row.String.Replace(...)` will return you a string, since you are not assigning it anything it will get discarded. It will not change the original `rowString` object.

You may use `String.Empty` or `""` to replace double quotes with an empty string, instead of single space `' '`. So your statement should be:

```
rowString = rowString.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();
```

*(Remember to pass **double quote as a string** `"\""`, since the method overload with string.Empty will require both the parameters to be of type string).*

You may get rid of `Trim()` at the end, if you were trying to remove spaces adding during `string.Replace` at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I was about to :), Its modified now

Comment: @Habib, it works fine but how to remove the spaces. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: @Habib, I used string.Empty, but it gives the error message as "String.Replace(char,char) has some invalid arguments. Thanks

Comment: @John, Missed one thing, update the answer, you should pass double quote as string. Statement should be: `rowString = rowString.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();`. Check the updated answer

Comment: @Habib, Thank You very much. Working fine as expected.

Answer (score 23):

Trim can remove any character(s), not just whitespace.

```
myString = myString.Trim('"');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Trim()` to simultaneously remove any combination of whitespaces, single quotes and double quotes:

```
rowString.Trim('"', '\'', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a common mistake. Here's what you need to do:

```
rowString = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

**Be sure to return your result to a variable** (`rowString =`). If you do not do this, C# will still run the methods but it will not modify the variable. This is the case with any *[immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*.

Example:

```
rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

will **not** modify the actual `rowString` object.

```
rowString = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

replaces the old value of `rowString` with the result of the code on the right.

I wrote this answer and just realized that Habib explained the exact same thing above. :)

Answer (score 0):

This row contains a error.

```
rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

Since both replace and trim returns a string you need to assign this to a variable.
By not assigning the string you will loose the value generated by the replace and trim methods.

```
var myString = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim(); 
//Or
rowString = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB you must try this :

```
Replace("""", "");
```

But in C# you must try this :

```
Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`rowString.Replace('"', ' ')` creates a new string object and do not modify the existing string object.so you will have to assign the newly created string object to a different variable or overwrite your existing variable.

```
rowString=rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim()    
or
var somestring=rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Habib mentioned, Strings are immutable. Any string manipulation needs to be set back with the manipulated data like Replace,Reverse, etc....

So try assigning the replaced string to get your desired behavior acheived.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
string str = "\"city\"";
string unescapedStr = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
```

OutPut: "city"