# How to get extention from given string?

Tags: c#

I have string "\"screenshot.png\"" .

I want to get the extension of string that is `.png`, I have tried the following but not working what changes i have to make?

```
string p = ""\"screenshot.png\""";

string e = Path.GetExtension(p);
if (e == ".txt")
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: you compare your exctension with `.txt` but it's `.png` that's never true

Comment: i have edited code

Comment: the problem is with the format of string

Comment: Does your string really contains a starting and trailing double-quote? with `Path.GetExtension` you´d probably get an ArgumentException as `"` is an invalid character within a path.

Comment: It is still not clear what "not working" means. Dou you get an exception? What result do you expect towards what do you actually get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be comparing e with ".png" but before that you would need to trim the path
So

```
var path = "\"screenshot.png\"";    
path = path.Replace("\"","");
var e = Path.GetExtension(path);
if(e == ".png")
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you copied the `Replace` code from Kason's answer - OP said nothing about parsing out those slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = "\"screenshot.png\"";    
p = p.Replace("\"","");
string e = Path.GetExtension(p); // It would show .png
```

Try to remove some " sign, because it is not related to the path.

> I have string "\"screenshot.png\"" .

So that the string should be `"\"\"screenshot.png\"\""`
However,even the string is the above one or the string in my code example, it work fine.

Comment: @un-lucky `""\"screenshot.png\"""` is not a valid string.

Comment: @un-lucky No matter the input is what, the main problem of this is how to remove the " sign.

Comment: then better you flag the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740486/want-to-remove-the-double-quotes-from-the-strings

Comment: @un-lucky Seems some of your answers can flag the question to solve, but you dont do it. I am just follow you.

Comment: Glad to hear that from you, All the very best

Answer (score 0):

If your input reaally contains double-quotes you have to remove them because they are no valid characters for paths. Thus use `path.Replace("\"", "")` before calling to `Path.GetExtension`, as Mason already suggested. Otherwise the method throws an `ArgumentException`.

EDIT: `" "\"screenshot.png\"" "` is not even a valid string, it should be `" \"screenshot.png\" "`, as un-lucky already edited, or even simpler `@"""screenshot.png"""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string p = "\"screenshot.png\"";
string temp = p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf('.'));
Console.WriteLine(p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf('.'),temp.LastIndexOf("\"")));
```

Try the above code

Comment: Deleted Thanks
New here :)