# Excel Function concatenate returns with an unexpected, additional double quotes Character

Tags: excel, function, debugging, excel-formula, syntax-error

I am using a rather "dirty hack" in Excel to add data to a temporary SQL table. I simply rwite data in form of sql statements to Excel cells and then I copy the output to SQL Server. Therefore it is important that the indent and the exact values in Excel are correct.

Now my Excel function works for most of my columns except in some it is adding an additional double quotes character. I am wondering, how can I rewrite this function to avoid this behaviour?

This is the function:

```
=VERKETTEN("'";E8;"' [";E$6;"] ,")
```

In most cases it returns this desired output as the Excel value:

```
'4333' [Departure Date],
```

but for some columns it returns this:

```
"'Tom' [PassengerFirst name] ,"
```

Is it true that I could use Char(34) to avoid this problem? What would the snytax look like?

Edit: This is not a programming question, this question is about Excel workbook functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to remove the double quotes from the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740486/want-to-remove-the-double-quotes-from-the-strings)

Comment: Your syntax seems fine. Please confirm that the custom formatting of your columns is not `\"@\"`. Also, for those wondering: `VERKETTEN` = `CONCATENATE`

Comment: @jvdV Thanks for your reply. How would I check the cell formatting ?

Comment: If it is not the formatting as suggested by JvdV it sounds like a periodic issue. So just to test if it could be some bug with the function, could you try the basic joining of strings? ie.: ="'"&E8&"' ["&E$6&"] ,"

Comment: Yes formatting did not work. I ended up just reading it with Python and then genereted a text file with the SQL statements. But for reference I will try your suggestion @Jones